# Are they're any ovens that have Programmable Stove top element features like an OVEN start stop feature?

Tags: electric-stoves

I love my Frigidaire Gallery electric Stove/convection oven.  It has made me a real fan of electric over gas. Most desirable is the superior control and evenness on the stove top. Especially for medium to low heat slow cooking and stewing. I could completely eliminate my crock pot if one or more of the heating elements had a delay/start/stop feature identical to the oven feature.  I can't seem to find that feature anywhere from any brand. Also i used to have an electric oven that allowed for 2 temperatures and times. THAT was cool also.  So say i wanted it to cook for 30 minutes @ 500 then turn down to 350 for 3 hours.  Also a cool feature hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some Siemans hobs have that feature.

http://www.siemens-home.com/Files/Siemens/Gb/en/Document/SiemensBuiltIn09_Hobs.pdf