# Are there stoves with automatic shutoff burners?

Tags: stove

It's so easy to burn food; all it takes is one distraction. And oil fires are no fun (do **not** use water). I am looking for a stove (either gas and electric) where the burners can be set on a timer and automatically shut themselves off, much like microwaves. It would be better still if heat profiles such as "high for 5 min, then simmer for 20 min" could be programmed and then reused. Is such a stove on the market?

A closely related question was asked [back in 2013](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/are-theyre-any-ovens-that-have-programmable-stove-top-element-features-like-an) but the answer has a broken link and is very out of date.

Comment: There might be some appliances that work like this.  The instant pot will switch out of ‘sauté’ mode after 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are they're any ovens that have Programmable Stove top element features like an OVEN start stop feature?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/are-theyre-any-ovens-that-have-programmable-stove-top-element-features-like-an)

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is very out of date with a broken link.

Comment: I want this! I want a normal full-size smart range and oven, both with ability to automate the times and temperatures via script or remote. Probe thermometer support would be sweet! Imagine these scenarios: 1. Rice: Bring pot to a boil, then simmer for 20 min, then turn off. 2. Bread preheat: At 5am, set oven to 550°F and set alarm timer notification for 1 hour. 3. Roast: Bake until prob thermometer reaches 120°F then turn off the oven. 4. Season cast iron: Heat to 550°F for 30 min, then turn off. So many possibilities!

Comment: @Beausmith: A raspberry PI that can turn the burner dials with drive belts? Safety first: if the temperature (thermal IR camera and/or computer vision of visible burning) gets too high sound an alarm and then the human turns things off. In addition to a fire blanket which should be in all kitchens (multiple safety features!). It can also remind the human when it's time to stir or flip.

Comment: I would also love a stove top that beeped every X minutes to warn me that it is still on.  Maybe I can piggy back a "is there anything like that?" question here.

Comment: @beausmith At least for *ovens* both timer and temperature probe driven controls is well established in the market. I used to program mine with sequences like “turn on  to <temp> at <time>, cook for <time>, turn off”. Bought it in 2005, iirc. A Bosch/Siemens/Neff Model. Covering use cases 2-4 in your comment.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am afraid we follow the no-shopping-recommendations rule of most of the Stack Exchange network. This means that the "are there" part of the question is already answered in the old one. If you meant to ask "who sells such ovens", this is off-topic, so it cannot be the factor which separates the new question from the old one. If you meant something else by outdated, and were not asking about current models, you can edit accordingly.

Comment: don't think you'll find anything for gas, but many induction stoves offer timers, and will also auto-shutoff if the pan/pot/etc is removed